# Opposite of zip(*[iter(s)]*n)

Tags: python, iterator

Dividing a list into equal chunks is neatly done using the `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` idiom. Is there a nice way of undoing it?

For example, if I have the following code:

```
>>> s = [3,4,1,2]
>>> zip(*[iter(s)]*2)
[(3, 4), (1, 2)]
```

Is there some function `func([(3,4),(1,2)]` that will yield `[3,4,1,2]` as the output?

Edit:

Timing and more solutions can be found in the question linked to by Dominic Kexel below.

Comment: You're right. It's the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = [(3, 4), (1, 2)]
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(s))
[3, 4, 1, 2]
```

However you could also use a nested list comprehension.

```
>>> s = [(3, 4), (1, 2)]
>>> [i for sub in s for i in sub]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Please don't use `l` as a variable name. It looks too much like `1` in some fonts. PEP8 even mentions it.

Comment: @gnibbler thanks for the reminder, fixed `;)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce:

```
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.add, [(3,4),(1,2)])
(3, 4, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? Just because it returns a tuple, rather than a list?

Comment: @juniper It might have been because reduce was is deprecated in Python 3000. Guess it depends what version you're using. http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: @juniper I guess you know, but you can cast the output to a list with list(reduce(...))

Comment: The python 3000 thing is important, I suppose. Thanks!

Comment: @juniper- maybe because `reduce(operator.add, ...` is really awful slow compared to `itertools.chain.from_iterable`. So some timing with larger inputs, and you'll notice a big difference.

Comment: Downvote is for useless and wrong answers, not for something that is corrrect, but not optimal.

Comment: @Dominic Kexel: Right you are. Nevertheless, it's still a valid answer.

Comment: @juniper- Never said this answer is invalid, I just guessed that it was downvoted because of that.